# What is the problem with my pangram javascript?

Tags: javascript

Pangram is a function that gets an input and check it if it has all alphabet ,This is my code i used ASCII code  :

```
function pangram(x) {
    var a;

    for (var i = 97; i < 122; i++) {
        a = "&#" + i + ";";
        if (x.toLowerCase().includes(a) !== true) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i === 122) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I think the problem is `a = "&#" + i + ";" ;` but i don't know why it can be a problem , it should work ...

Comment: if `x` is a string - then `includes` would check each of its _characters_. Character is a one codepoint. Variable `a` holds 5 or 6 characters, hence it never matches. What does `a` represent at all? It looks like an xml entity, it's not obvious though what your problem has to do with them. Perhaps you need `String.fromCodePoint`?

Comment: @Henieh: YOu are using `i==122` outside the `for` loop. The brackets are already closed. Can you put a code where there are no errors. Better to provide a code on plunkr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `charCodeAt()` instead of making a manual one. Replace if condition to this :

```
if(x.toLowerCase().includes(String.fromCharCode(i))!==true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have come close to the answer, yet there are a few issues with the code,

1. **a = "&#" + i + ";";**, what does this do? You can use String.fromCharCode(65); to get the character for a given ASCII value. More info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp
2. You can just exit the loop and the function if a character was not found, no point continuing after that point.

```js
function pangram(x) {
    var a;

    for (var i = 97; i < 122; i++) {
        a = String.fromCharCode(i);;
        if (x.toLowerCase().includes(a) !== true) {
          // if atleast one letter was not found, we exit the function and the loop
          return false;
      }
    }

    // if it comes here, that means all the letters were found
    return true;
}

var isPangram = pangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
console.log(isPangram);
```

Comment: "You cannot access i after the loop ended" --- you definitely can

Comment: Yes my bad, it is a global variable since he has used var. I will edit that part out